# How to get certain result in array from elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got some issues about query the data from elasticsearch. I would like to query the data

that has structure as following:

```
[
{
     name : 'myName',
     dailyTasks : [
         {
             date : '2016-01-01',
             task : 'task1'
         },
         {
             date : '2016-01-02',
             task : 'task2'
         },
         {
             date : '2016-01-03',
             task : 'task3'
         }
     ]
},
{
     name : 'myName1',
     dailyTasks : [
         {
             date : '2016-01-01',
             task : 'task11'
         },
         {
             date : '2016-01-02',
             task : 'task12'
         },
         {
             date : '2016-01-03',
             task : 'task13'
         }
     ]
}
]
```

I would like to know how to get the results such as following:

```
[
{
     name : 'myName',
     dailyTasks : [
         {
             date : '2016-01-01',
             task : 'task1'
         },
         {
             date : '2016-01-02',
             task : 'task2'
         }
     ]
}
]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the mapping of your `dailyTasks` field?

Comment: All I can say is the `dailyTasks` is not `nested`, but I've re-indexed to make `dailyTasks` as `nested` object. But I still cannot query the results that I posted.

Comment: `nested` is the way to go. Then you also need [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) and it will work

Answer (score 0):

What kind of logic shall the Query have ?
It seems like name: myName1 and date <'2016-01-02' ?

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {}
          ],
          "must": [
            { "term": {
      "name": "myName"
    }
              "range": {
                "date": {
                  "gte": "2016-01-01",
                  "lte": "2016-01-02"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But the `date` is in list named `dailyTasks`, should we concern about reference from dailyTasks?

Comment: sure you can write dailyTasks.date , i did not do any tests, just wanted to point out how the query could be.
Another option is to filter first by name, and then aggregate that result on date / and or filter out ranges of the date ...